Filtering duplicate values, searching for pairs
We have a plugin, which imports an XML file from an FTP server into the database. This XML is further processed, and data is inserted into the database tables. These rows are added to the "pricing" table (with help of the package w 10k+ rows), where prices can be set. My problem is that duplicate values often come through during the import. The system processes them, but during pairing, only the first match is taken into table.
To simplify, there is a table.. the important columns are: the ID, the column "SITE", and the column LINKED, where the ID is attached with an exclamation mark (!) to the PK.
How can I find the pairs and filter out those that don’t have a pair or those that are linked to the same ID more than once?
After this, I would like to make a procedure to update the column to fix the pairing - with the correct ID.
table:

I have colored the pairs to make it easier to visualize and understand what the issue is. Here you can see, that SITE: 292 ID: 4 is not paired to ID:6.
I have no IDEA, how can i link the correct.. i can find the not good one-s, with sub-select:
select * from pricing p where p.PK='3452400012026' 
 and p.site='292' 
 and 
 (select count(*) from pricing po 
  where po.PK = p.PK and 
   po.LINKED=p.PK||'!'||p.ID) != 1

So if it's not 1, it's problematic...

EDIT:

SQL FIDDLE WITH COMMENTS

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data (as text we can copy-paste-and-execute, not images); an English explanation of the logic you are trying to implement (including the relevance of the pk field which is not included in your sample data and why sites 99 and 292 are related or if those are just magic numbers); and the expected output.

If I'm not wrong - this could be done with SQL alone using MERGE INTO to do the update. Here is the code with link to the fiddle. Details below the code:
MERGE INTO PRICING p
USING ( WITH
            links AS
                ( Select     p.ID, p.LINKED, p.SITE, p.PK, 
                             To_Number(Substr(p.LINKED, InStr(p.LINKED, '!') + 1)) "LINK_ID",
                             Case When p.LINKED Is Not Null
                                  Then Row_Number() Over(Partition By p.SITE, p.PK, To_Number(Substr(p.LINKED, InStr(p.LINKED, '!') + 1))
                                                         Order By p.SITE, p.PK, p.ID) 
                             End "RN_LINK",
                             Count(p.ID) Over(Partition By p.SITE, p.PK, To_Number(Substr(p.LINKED, InStr(p.LINKED, '!') + 1))) "COUNT_LINK"
                  From       pricing p
                  Where      p.LINKED Is Not Null
                ),
            grid AS
                ( Select   * 
                    From links
                  UNION ALL
                   Select     ID, LINKED, SITE, PK, ID, 
                              Row_Number() Over(Partition By SITE, PK Order By ID), 
                              Count(ID) Over()
                   From       pricing
                   Where      LINKED Is Null And
                              ID Not In(Select LINK_ID From links)
                )
--    M a i n   S Q L :
        SELECT   *   
        FROM   ( Select     g.ID, g.LINKED, g.SITE, g.PK, 
                            Case When g.COUNT_LINK > 1 And
                                      g.LINKED Is Not Null And
                                      g.RN_LINK = 1 
                                 Then g.PK || '!' || g.LINK_ID
                                 When g.COUNT_LINK > 1 And 
                                      g.RN_LINK > 1 And 
                                      g.ID != g.LINK_ID
                                 Then g.PK || '!' || ( Select ID From grid Where LINKED Is Null And RN_LINK = g.RN_LINK - 1 )
                           End "LINKED_2"
                 From     grid g
               )
        WHERE    LINKED_2 Is Not Null And SubStr(LINKED_2, -1) != '!'
    ) x ON (x.ID = p.ID)
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE SET p.LINKED = x.LINKED_2
WHERE p.LINKED != x.LINKED_2

See the fiddle and the result here.
Details:

create a cte (links) to get ID - LINK_ID paires by extracting LINK_ID from LINKED column ...

--    l i n k s :
/*
ID  LINKED           SITE PK            LINK_ID RN_LINK COUNT_LINK
--- ---------------  ---- ------------- ------- ------- ----------
1   3452400012026!2  99   3452400012026       2       1          1
3   3452400012026!8  99   3452400012026       8       1          2
5   3452400012026!7  99   3452400012026       7       1          1
6   3452400012026!8  99   3452400012026       8       2          2
9   3452400012026!10 99   3452400012026      10       1          1      */
--  here we have the ID - LINK_ID pairs along with row numbers per LINK_ID with total rows per LINK_ID
--  notice that LINK_ID 8 has two rows - for IDs 3 and 6


Create another cte (grid) to union the rows with null in LINKED column not present in the links cte above

--    g r i d 
/*
ID  LINKED           SITE PK            LINK_ID RN_LINK COUNT_LINK
--- ---------------  ---- ------------- ------- ------- ----------
1   3452400012026!2  99   3452400012026       2       1          1
3   3452400012026!8  99   3452400012026       8       1          2
4   null             292  3452400012026       4       1          1
5   3452400012026!7  99   3452400012026       7       1          1
6   3452400012026!8  99   3452400012026       8       2          2
9   3452400012026!10 99   3452400012026      10       1          1      */


In main sql generate LINKED_2 column for rows with duplicate LINK_IDs (ID 3 and 6) using row not present in links (ID 4):


first duplicate row (RN_LINK = 1) will have the LINK_ID as it already has
ssecond duplicate row (RN_LINK = 2) will fetch the first not paired ID ffrom grid (4 in this case)
if there was third same LINK_ID the correlated subquery would try to fetch the second not paired ID ... and so on ...

--    m a i n : 
/*
ID  LINKED            SITE  PK              LINKED_2
--  ----------------  ----  --------------  ---------------
 3  3452400012026!8   99    3452400012026   3452400012026!8
 6  3452400012026!8   99    3452400012026   3452400012026!4      */

The resulting dataset is MERGED INTO pricing to do the update.

You question appears to be to find the rows that are not highlighted in your image.
You can use the ROW_NUMBER analytic to number the rows to find the duplicates for each combination of pk, site and linked.
To find the unreferenced rows, you can split the linked column into linked_pk and linked_id sub-strings before and after the ! character, respectively, and then use a hierarchical query to connect to the parent rows. If there are rows with no connections then they are unmatched.
You can combine this into a single query:
WITH links (pk, site, id, linked, linked_pk, linked_id, rn) AS (
  SELECT pk,
         site,
         id,
         linked,
         SUBSTR(linked, 1, INSTR(linked, '!') - 1),
         SUBSTR(linked, INSTR(linked, '!') + 1),
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY pk, site, linked
           ORDER BY ROWNUM
         )
  FROM   pricing
)
SELECT pk,
       site,
       id, 
       linked
FROM   links l
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR pk = linked_pk
AND    PRIOR id = linked_id
AND    rn = 1
GROUP BY pk, site, id, linked
HAVING MAX(LEVEL) = 1;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE pricing (pk, site, id, linked) AS
SELECT '123',  99,  1, '345!2'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123',  99,  3, '345!8'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123',  99,  5, '345!7'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123',  99,  6, '345!8'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123',  99,  9, '345!10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '345', 292,  2, NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '345', 292,  4, NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '345', 292,  7, NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '345', 292,  8, NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '345', 292, 10, NULL     FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



PK
SITE
ID
LINKED




123
99
6
345!8


345
292
4





If you want the valid links then split linked into sub-strings and the connect the table to itself using EXISTS or JOIN:
WITH links (pk, site, id, linked, linked_pk, linked_id, rn) AS (
  SELECT pk,
         site,
         id,
         linked,
         SUBSTR(linked, 1, INSTR(linked, '!') - 1),
         SUBSTR(linked, INSTR(linked, '!') + 1),
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY pk, site, linked
           ORDER BY ROWNUM
         )
  FROM   pricing
)
SELECT pk, id, site, linked, linked_pk, linked_id
FROM   links c
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   links p
         WHERE  p.pk = c.linked_pk
         AND    p.id = c.linked_id
       )
AND    rn = 1;

Which outputs:



PK
SITE
ID
LINKED
LINKED_PK
LINKED_ID




123
99
1
345!2
345
2


123
99
5
345!7
345
7


123
99
3
345!8
345
8


123
99
9
345!10
345
10



fiddle

I appreciate your response! "You question appears to be to find the rows that are not highlighted in your image." That's correct. My goal is to update the values in the LINKED column with the correct ID (removing duplicates). I’ve added an SQL FIDDLE with comments to make it easier to understand what I’m trying to achieve.. sorry, im not native english speaker. BTW, You swapped ID and SITE....

@Georg id and site unswapped.

Site 99 and site 292 are supposed to have a 1:1 relation (one purchase price, one sales price). But you know that sometimes there are site 292 that either have no site 99 relation or more than one. You want to find them. This is easily done with an outer join.
with
  s292 as (select * from pricing where site = 292),
  s99 as (select * from pricing where site = 99)
select
  s292.id as id_292,
  case when count(s99.id) > 0 then listagg(s99.id || ' = ' || s99.linked, ', ') within group (order by s99.id) end as link_99
from s292 
left join s99 on s99.linked like '%!' || s292.id
group by s292.id
having count(s99.id) <> 1
order by id_292;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/JXdkyY1E
You also want to fix data automatically. But can this be done automatically? In below example we have two duplicate 99s and two 292s with missing partners. How would you tell, which rows to relate? It looks to me like this can only be done manually, if at all.



SITE
ID
LINKED




99
1
11111!5


99
2
33333!6


99
3
33333!6


99
4
11111!5


292
5



292
6



292
7



292
8




